Can't update data source with DataAdapter
I am experimenting with DataSets and DataAdapters in Visual Studio. So, I have a toy table (teacher) in MySQL with two columns: id (PK) and AM (int(11)). In a WinForm, a textbox is bound to AM:
string queryString = "SELECT id,  AM from teacher where id=1;";
adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(queryString, conn);
teacher = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(teacher, "teacher");
textBox6.DataBindings.Add("Text", teacher.Tables[0], "AM");

The binding is one way successful, i.e the textbox displays the value of the column.
I also have a button which, when pressed, will update the Database table with the value the user enters in the textbox:
var updateTeacherCmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE teacher SET AM=@AM WHERE id=@id;", conn);
MySqlParameter param1 = new MySqlParameter("@AM", MySqlDbType.Int32, 4, "AM");
updateTeacherCmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
MySqlParameter param2 = new MySqlParameter("@id", MySqlDbType.Int32, 4,"id");
param2.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;
updateTeacherCmd.Parameters.Add(param2);
adapter.UpdateCommand = updateTeacherCmd;
        
adapter.Update(teacher,"teacher");
MessageBox.Show(adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText);

But the teacher table is not updated. 
I have succesfully updated the datasource with the use of:
var updateTeacherCmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE teacher SET AM=textBox6.Text WHERE id=1;", conn);
updateTeacherCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

but I would like to know why the datadapter method fails.

Attention: SET AM=textBox6.Text  That can't have worked.

What is the relation between the Parameter's name and the Source Column's name, and what are those two used for? -- As mentioned, this: UPDATE teacher SET AM=textBox6.Text WHERE id=1; wasn't exceedingly successful -- See also: MySqlCommandBuilder

Lars, yes. now var updateTeacherCmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE teacher SET am=" + Int32.Parse(textBox6.Text) + " WHERE id=1;", conn); does the trick

One small problem: the parameters don't match
You need to ensure that the parameters in MySqlCommand and MySqlParameter are the same.
In your example, the parameter names set in MySqlCommand are @AM and @id respectively, but the parameter names set in MySqlParameter are @PROYP_MERES and @id respectively.
In a way, you need to change the code:
var updateTeacherCmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE teacher SET AM=@AM WHERE id=@id;" , conn);
MySqlParameter param1 = new MySqlParameter("@AM", MySqlDbType.Int32, 11, "AM");
updateTeacherCmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
MySqlParameter param2 = new MySqlParameter("@id", MySqlDbType.Int32, 11, "id");

In addition, you can modify the dataset value to update the database table like this:
 MySqlDataAdapter adapter;
 DataSet teacher;
MySqlConnection conn =new MySqlConnection("");
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string queryString = "SELECT id,  AM from teacher where id=1;";
    adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(queryString, conn);
    teacher = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(teacher, "teacher");
    textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", teacher.Tables[0], "AM");
}
 
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 
    var updateTeacherCmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE teacher SET AM=@AM WHERE id=@id;", conn);
    MySqlParameter param1 = new MySqlParameter("@AM", MySqlDbType.Int32, 11, "AM");
    updateTeacherCmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
    MySqlParameter param2 = new MySqlParameter("@id", MySqlDbType.Int32, 11, "id");
    param2.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;
    updateTeacherCmd.Parameters.Add(param2);
    adapter.UpdateCommand = updateTeacherCmd;
    if (teacher.Tables["teacher"].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        teacher.Tables["teacher"].Rows[0]["AM"] = textBox2.Text;
    }
    adapter.Update(teacher, "teacher");
    MessageBox.Show(adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText);
}


Yes you are right. I corrected that but still the problem remains. I also corrected the mysqlparameters as follows: MySqlParameter param1 = new MySqlParameter("@AM", MySqlDbType.Int32, 4, "AM"); and MySqlParameter param1 = new MySqlParameter("@id", MySqlDbType.Int32, 4, "id");

MySqlParameter param2 = new MySqlParameter("@id", MySqlDbType.Int32, 4, "id");

See my latest editted part of the answer. @nikos chatziathanasiou

Ok, I have solved the issue.
The trick was to call EndEdit() on the datarow (or dataset) who had changed and then proceed with the update() on the datadapter:
        DataRow myrow;
        myrow=teacher.Tables[0].Rows[0];
        myrow.EndEdit();

        var updateTeacherCmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE teacher SET AM=@AM WHERE id=1;", conn);
        MySqlParameter param1 = new MySqlParameter("@AM", MySqlDbType.Int32, 4, "AM");
        updateTeacherCmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
        MySqlParameter param2 = new MySqlParameter("@id", MySqlDbType.Int32, 4,"id");
        param2.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;
        updateTeacherCmd.Parameters.Add(param2);
        adapter.UpdateCommand = updateTeacherCmd;

        adapter.Update(teacher,"teacher");

